# How can I synchronize two java applications?

Tags: java, memory, synchronization, distributed

Here is a situation I have encountered: I have two similair java application running on different servers. Both applications obtain data from the same website using web-service provided. But the site doesn't know of course that the first app has taken the same peace of data as the second app. After fetching data should be saved in database. So I have a problem of saving the same data two times in a database.

How can I avoid duplicate entries in my db?

Probably there are two ways:

1) use database side. write something that looks like "insert if unique".

2) use server side. write some intermediate service that will receive responses from two data fetchers and process them somehow.

I suppose second solution is more effecient.

Can you advice something on this topic?
How would you implement that intermediate service? How would implement communication between the services? If we would use the HashMaps to store received data, how can we estimate maximum size of HashMap that our system can handle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need to fetch data at two servers simultaneously? Checking every entry during *insert if not present* could be expensive. Merging several fetches can be time consuming as well. Is there any benefit of fetching in parallel? Consider having one fetcher at time.

The problem you will face is that you have to choose which one of you distributed processes should perform  data fetching and storing it in DB.

It is some kind of [Leader Election](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leader_election) problem.

Take a look at [Apache ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/) which is distributed coordination service.
There is a [receipt](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/recipes.html#sc_leaderElection) how to implement leader election with ZooKeeper.

There are a lot of frameworks that already implemented this receipt. I'd recommend you to use [Netflix curator](https://github.com/Netflix/curator). More details about the leader election with curator is available at [wiki](https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki/Leader-Election).

Comment: Mairbek, thanks for reply. A problem with this approach is that all my applications should be absolutely identical. So I cannot place the fetching piece of code into first app, and do not place it into second one. Or you mean Apache Zookeeper can solve this issue? Really, I suppose this can be a third way to solve this problem: create a service that runs fetching routine on only one of the apps. In other words I need something that produces signals for my apps to make fetch operation.

Comment: The code that you are running should be identical. You just need a consensus between distributed process which one of them should act as a leader.

For example if you have two identical servers. On a start time both of them have to decide which one of them is a leader. This can be done using ZooKeeper. If first service is a leader it fetches the data and persists it to the DB second one is idle and vise versa.

Comment: This means I should do something for this - change properties files, change app code, code this from some app properties etc This would make my apps not totally identical. Or you suggest using some external service will select the leader?

Comment: As I understand you have a same code base for both deployed apps. I suggest you to modify it (add leader election code). Then deploy a new version to both servers. The code should be identical. ZooKeeper is an external service that allows leader selection.

Answer (score 4):

There are distributed frameworks for this sort of problem.

- [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/) - will allow you to have a single distributed `ConcurrentMap` across multiple JVM's.
- [Terracotta](http://terracotta.org/) - Using it's DSO (Distributed shared objects I think) it will maintain a Map implementation across JVM;s